# SQL query LIKE from another table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL query which takes values from another table and puts in LIKE %%:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  contacts xa
WHERE
  lower(xa.title) in (
    select
      lower(title)
    from
      contacts con
      inner join ce_campaign_spec_tb camp on lower(con.title) ilike '%' || trim(
        both ' '
        from
          camp.param_val
      ) || '%'
    where
      job_id = '18649b38-ce57-48ba-ac52-9e95085df3f9'
      and param = 'title'
      and relation_id = 1
  )
```

The above query takes 2 minutes to execute. How to rewrite this query to perform better?

The EXPLAIN looks like this:

```
XN Hash IN Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=1183647.16..12653156935.52 rows=2075741 width=801)
  Hash Cond: (lower(("outer".title)::text) = lower(("inner".title)::text))
  ->  XN Seq Scan on contacts xa  (cost=0.00..20757.41 rows=2075741 width=801)
  ->  XN Hash  (cost=1183569.31..1183569.31 rows=31137 width=32)
        ->  XN Nested Loop DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=427.16..1183569.31 rows=31137 width=32)
              Join Filter: (lower(("outer".title)::text) ~~* (('%'::text || btrim(("inner".param_val)::text, ' '::text)) || '%'::text))
              ->  XN Seq Scan on contacts con  (cost=0.00..20757.41 rows=2075741 width=32)
              ->  XN Materialize  (cost=427.16..427.19 rows=3 width=21)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on ce_campaign_spec_tb camp  (cost=0.00..331.15 rows=3 width=21)
                          Filter: (((job_id)::text = '18649b38-ce57-48ba-ac52-9e95085df3f9'::text) AND ((relation_id)::text = '1'::text) AND ((param)::text = 'title'::text))
----- Nested Loop Join in the query plan - review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products -----
```

Comment: It would help if you provided sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

The EXPLAIN plan suggests that the biggest cost is:

```
XN Hash IN Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=1183647.16..12653156935.52 rows=2075741 width=801)
```

This is the whole `IN` sub-select, which has 2 million rows. In addition, it is indicating `DS_BCAST_INNER` which is defined on [Evaluating the query plan - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_data_redistribution.html) as *"A copy of the entire inner table is broadcast to all the compute nodes."*

So, it's basically saying that it is sending a lot of data between nodes and each of those rows needs to have vales converted via `lower()`, so it is very hard to make the query efficient.

First, make sure that the tables are using appropriate Distribution Keys (`DISTKEY`) and Sort Keys (`SORTKEY`). The fact that the table is being broadcast to all compute nodes suggests that the tables are not distributed on the same key. A good rule-of-thumb is that the `DISTKEY` should be set to the field that is most commonly used in `JOINs`. So, check that `contacts` and `ce_campaign_spec_tb` have a column with the same values as their `DISTKEY`, and avoid using computation in the JOINed value (that is, join on the raw column rather than a value computed from the column value) since that will avoid any benefit from using a `DISTKEY` anyway.

There is also a large cost on the `INNER JOIN`, possibly because of the complexity of the join (lower, ilike, trim). If possible, pre-compute this conversion and store it as another field. If the queries can be simplified to match actual values without any conversions (eg `lower()` and `ilike`), then the database can greatly optimize the query. An important concept in a data warehouse is to have **wide tables**, which means you can create additional columns that might duplicate data, but make it easier to query. For example, you could store a lowercase title on every contract, just to avoid having to cast it to lowercase in every query.

I also don't see why it is doing the `IN` subquery in the first place. It is basically saying:

```
SELECT contract where contract IN (SELECT contract where...)
```

Can you remove that outer select? That would avoid moving around the `contracts` table again.

Comment: In my ce_campaign_spec_tb table, I have a column called as param_value which has values similar to contact table's title, primary_function, role column. Should I create distkey on param_value, and title, primary_function, role?

Comment: A `DISTKEY` determines which rows are put on which nodes, via a hash function. If two tables have the same column as the `DISTKEY`, then all rows for a given value will reside on the same node. For example, say you have a User table with a username of `foo`, and a History table with a username of `foo`. Both tables would keep the `foo` row on the same node. This means that a JOIN can operate on data that is stored on the same node, without having to send it between nodes. So, it is only useful to define a `DISTKEY` if that column will be used in the JOIN. Only one column can be the DISTKEY.

Comment: The issue is ce_campaign_spec_tb has param_value which has aggregated values and not from one column of another table.

Comment: Given that your query is joining on a computed value of `lower(title)` and `lower() ilike blah`, Redshift cannot optimize the JOIN. That's why I was suggesting that you have another column that stores the lowercase of the title, so it can directly JOIN to that field, but that's only useful if you are using the raw value of the column to JOIN. I would recommend you start by removing the outer query if possible.

Comment: I will remove lower. Should I still use ilike OR use like?

Comment: If you want an efficient query, find a way to avoid using computed values in the JOIN.